# Unable to cross-compile openSSH for arm, zlib missing

Tags: compiling, cross-compilation

I'm trying to cross-compile openSSH for ARMs but it seems that i'm unsuccessful:

Here're my configure parameters:

```
./configure --host=arm CC=arm-hisiv400-linux-g++ --prefix=/home/aa/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/openSSH --with-zlib=/usr/include

checking zlib.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: zlib.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: zlib.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: zlib.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: zlib.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: zlib.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------- ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to openssh-unix-dev@mindrot.org ##
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------- ##
checking for zlib.h... no
configure: error: *** zlib.h missing - please install first or check config.log ***
```

Could anyone advise why although zlib.h is present but unable to compile?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by installing zlib development files:

```bsh
# Debian-based
sudo apt install libz-dev

# Fedora-based
sudo dnf install zlib-devel
```

This is related to the last error you've got:

```
configure: error: *** zlib.h missing - please install first or check config.log ***
```

The warnings you've got would get solved by this also. However, if you have it installed, maybe try reinstalling or updating it.

- **Bonus:** One way to find required development shared libraries on your system is to ask your package manager what package provides a specific file. For example, `dnf provides` on Fedora could help you in these situations:

  ```
  $ sudo dnf provides /usr/include/zlib.h
  ...

  zlib-devel-1.2.11-30.fc35.x86_64 : Header files and libraries for Zlib development
  Repo        : @System
  Matched from:
  Filename    : /usr/include/zlib.h

  ...
  ```

Found the solution thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38277221/4215651).

Answer (score 2):

Probably `configure` has found a zlib.h for you host arch (/usr/include/zlib.h) and this is not usable for your target arch. See config.log for more details.

You need to build zlib using using the same cross compiler (`configure --host=arm CC=arm-hisiv400-linux-g++`). Or maybe your distribution provides a zlib devel package matching to your cross compiler.

In case you have zlib already installed to another prefix path you may need to tell configure about that, e.g.

./configure CFLAGS=-I/path/to/include LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/lib ...

or

./configure PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/lib/pkgconfig ...

Comment: actually I did use the same CC to build the sources. somehow when building openSSH it can't find the zlib. Btw, where may I find config.log file?

Comment: `config.log` should be in the build directory where you run ./configure. I've updated my answer regarding custom include paths.

Comment: btw, how do we verify if zlib is usable / suitable for my target arch?

Comment: @emddev just compile a minimal test file bla.c which has `#include "zlib.h".  `gcc -c  bla.c -o bla.o`. The compiler will give you error or success. That's basically the same what `configure` is doing. The config.log should show you the test code and gcc command verbosely.

Comment: thanks for the guidance, I think it's because zlib.h wasn't configured properly for my target arch. When I re-build zlib again and then rebuild openssh again, I was able to build openssh but new problems surfaced when I try to make

Comment: when I make, it says "Makefile:26: recipe for target 'arc4random.o' failed and also Makefile:142: recipe for target 'openbsd-compat/libopenbsd-compat.a' failed.